# How to style mat-select-panel?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I need to style mat-select-panel dropdown list width, since ::ng-deep is deprecated I'm trying to style it directly, but it's not working

HTML:

```
<mat-select
        panelClass="large-select"
        formControlName="asset"
        (closed)="onPanelClose(i)"
        (selectionChange)="assetSelected(i,$event)"
        [compareWith]="compareAsset">
```

CSS:

```
.large-select .mat-select-panel {
    width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Try `.large-select mat-form-field{width: 500px;}`

Comment: Still no success

Comment: use /deep/ .large-select .mat-select-panel{ }

Comment: /deep/ is deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the .css in styles.css **not** in component.css. Angular use [cdk-overlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview) when you use mat-select. A cdk-overlay is created "outside" the app.component, so you should use a .css defined in a global style.

NOTE: is `.cdk-overlay-pane .large-select`

If you see the [example](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#adding-custom-styles-to-the-dropdown-panel) you see that the component has [ViewEncapsulation.None](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation#description). ViewEncapsulation.None is another way to make the .css "global" (the problem using ViewEncapsulation.None is that **all** the .css in the component.css is applied to all the application (it's the reason I prefer add the .css in styles.css)

Comment: Can you post an example with code snippet, I'm new in Angular and may not understand how to gain apply changes from style.css to my current mat-select

Comment: @J.Klimov, I just "recicle" an old [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xud8k4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.html,src%2Fstyles.scss) see that the .css is in styles.scss. If you see the angular.json (in project-->architect-->build-->styles) you see an array. This array include the file /styles.scss. Angular create a bundle .css joining all the styles in this array puls the .css in your component.

Comment: So I don't need to add panelClass="large-select" to my html?

Comment: @J.Klimov, In .html of the component you need add panelClass: `<mat-select ... panelClass="large-select">` in styles.css you change the .css

Comment: Unfortunately not working, but thank you for your help

Comment: In the stackblitz, works. Try execute your application, using F12 check where is the class "large-panel" and see what .css is applied

Comment: It seems app cannot find declaration to large-select css

Comment: I moved forward, the mat-select changed color, but didn't changed width, interesting

Comment: if developers tools (F12) generally you have a section with "calculated css", check what .css is applied -perhafs a more "specific rule" avoid yours

Comment: Can you check my screen and point me to my mistake https://imgur.com/a/DUdNixW

Comment: try add also the rule `max-width` (really you should avoid use !important)

Comment: Thank you, max-width worked, you rock bro